# Dynamic polymorphic like model Laravel

Tags: database, oop, laravel, model, eloquent

I'm developing an application using Laravel 5.2.

I have made the migrations, and I have this tables.

```
Device table
 id
 owner_id
 description
 device_id
 type_id
```

this table is for generic device info, but when I call it, I'll need to access more deep info. Like this.

```
Mobile table
  id
  imei
  color
```

or

```
Computer table
  id
  cpu_speed
  ram_size
  disk_size
```

I want to to check the device_type and after that, call the properties for that, and bring to itself, so I could use something like `device->imei` or `device->ram_size`, directly without using an intermediate object like `device->subdevice->imei` (not as in [Polymorphic Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) is suggested)

Comment: What's your question? You want to use polymorphic relation but you don't want to use Laravel's polymorphic relation implemantation?

Comment: I don't know the name for it. Its similar to a polymorphic relation, but inside the device object.